# Implementation of ~> and <~ parser combinators operators

Tags: scala, parser-generator

Scala's source explains these operators:

`~> is a parser combinator for sequential composition which keeps only the right result.`

`<~ is a parser combinator for sequential composition which keeps only the left result`

I wrote the following two classes. Note that Daniel Spiewak's excellent [article](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/the-magic-behind-parser-combinators) on this topic helped me very much to begin to understand Parser Combinators.

`~>`

```
class KeepRightParser[+A](left: =>Parser[A], 
                         right: =>Parser[A]) extends Parser[A] {
    def apply(s: Stream[Character]) = left(s) match {
        case Success(_, rem) => right(rem)
        case f: Failure => f
    }
}
```

and `<~`:

```
class KeepLeftParser[+A](left: =>Parser[A], 
                         right: =>Parser[A]) extends Parser[A] {
    def apply(s: Stream[Character]) = left(s) match {
        case Success(a, rem) => right(rem) match { 
            case Success(_, _) => Success(a, rem)
            case f: Failure => f
        }
        case f: Failure => f
    }
}
```

Here's the test:

```
val s4 = Stream[Character]('f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r', 'b', 'u', 'z', 'z')
val krp = new KeepRightParser("foo", "bar")
println("~> test: " + krp(s4))

val klp = new KeepLeftParser("foo", "bar")
println("<~ test: " + klp(s4))
```

with output:

```
~> test: Success(bar,Stream(b, ?))
<~ test: Success(foo,Stream(b, a, r, b, ?))
```

As I understand, the second stream shows more than its **head** since `bar` needed to be read for parsing the second half of the sequence.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are correct. `Stream`'s `toString` isn't immutable as you can verify in the REPL:

```
scala> val s = Stream(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
s: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)

scala> s(3)
res5: Int = 4

scala> s
res6: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, 2, 3, 4, ?)
```

Comment: Thanks. Luigi, isn't it `immutable` since it `s`'s structure **cannot** change? But it's not `referentially transparent` since calling `s.toString` will not always output the same result?

Comment: The Stream itself is certainly immutable, so long as you don't consider its `toString` a core feature, which I wouldn't. I think you're technically correct that "referential transparency" is the correct term for whether a function always returns the same thing for given inputs, and "immutability" is a property of data structures / objects.